# Error TS1005: ';' expected when using firebase with angular

Tags: angular, firebase

So I was trying to create a simple demo of Push notification by firebase in Angular. After creating 'messaging.service' and implement it into base component, it return me with this error. This does not happen before I created 'messaging.service'. I have try `npm install typescript --save-dev` but it still failed.  Upgrade my typescript to other version return me with an error angular/comply can't regconize it.

My package.json

```
{   "name": "easyFirebase",   "version": "0.0.0",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run easyFirebase:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.10",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.3",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"   },   "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"   } }
```

My 'messaging.service'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingService {
  messaging = firebase.messaging();
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  private updateToken(token) {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return;
      }
      const data = { [user.uid]: token };
      this.db.object('fcmTokens/').update(data);
    });
  }

  getPermission() {
    Notification.requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Notify permission granted.');
        return this.messaging.getToken();
      }).then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        this.updateToken(token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to get permission.', err);
      });
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the code breaks? At which lines i mean.

Comment: It's said that 'ERROR in node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts'